# How to call a function in data-binding when lots of parameters are involved

Tags: data-binding, polymer, web-component

At the moment I have this in my template:

- **WAY 1**

  ```
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{_showCancel(userData.generic.id,info.userId,info._children.gigId.userId,info.accepted,info.cancelled,info.paymentTerms)}}">
  ```

And then this in my element:

```
  _showCancel: function(viewerUserId,offerUserId,gigUserId, accepted, cancel, paymentTerms) {

    // Offer needs to be accepted and NOT cancelled
    if (!info.accepted || info.cancelled) return false;

    // Gig owner can ALWAYS cancel an offer
    if (viewerUserId == gigUserId ) return true;

    // Offer maker can only cancel if the gig involved pre-payment
    if (viewerUserId == offerUserId && paymentTerms != 'on-day') return true;

    return false;
  },
```

Do I have just too many parameters to this function?

- **WAY 2**

Should I just have something like this instead:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_showCancel(userData, info)}}">
```

- **WAY 3**

Although I would want to check if their sub-properties change too... so I would need:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_showCancel(userData, info, userData.*, info.*)}}">
```

- **WAY 4**

But then again I probably should just look for the properties and use the `value` property like so:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_showCancel(userData.*, info.*)}}">
```

And then the function would be:

```
_showCancel: function(userDataObs, infoObs) {
  var userData = userDataObs.value;
  var info = infoObs.value;

  if( !userData || !info) return;

  ...
```

Questions:

- Do you see any fundamental mistakes with ways 1 to 4?
- Is WAY 1 really the best way to go about it? (it feels like it right now)
- Is WAY 3 an acceptable pattern?

## ADDENDUM

What would I do in cases where I have:

```
<paper-button 
  raised 
  hidden$="{{!_showCancel(item.id,userData.config.usersCategories,userData.config.userCategories,userData.config.usersCategories.*)}}"
>
Cancel
</paper-button>
```

(NOTE: `usersCategories` is an `Array`)
And `_showCancel` being:

```
  _showCancel: function(categoryId, userCategories) {
    for (var k in usersCategories) {
      var $ucat = usersCategories[k];

      if ($ucat.categoryId == categoryId) {
        if ($ucat.status == 'applied' || $ucat.status == 'granted') return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  },
```

The point being: I want both easy access to `usersCategories`, but don't want to get the value out of the "strange" array modifiers etc. So, is this a good pattern?

Comment: For the addendum: if you wish to detect array mutations, you need to listen to `<array>.*` or `<array>.splices` ([see spec](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#array-observation)). If you don't like _splices_ (the _strange modifiers_), then you can ignore them inside your function. But you should still pass both the array and the `.*` or `.splices` variable. Without it, the change won't be properly propagated. Your current code is actually OK. Except maybe for the `for/in`iteration. This is not a good way to iterate an array, use a simple `for` with `i` for index.

Comment: I have recently discovered that I could iterate an array with a for statement. I found it much easier! What's wrong with that?

Comment: All good I just figured it out :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**Way 1**" is the right one. **But**, you should only reference the variables that you need, and you should always use them as they are defined in your function header.

For example, you use:

`{{_showCancel(userData.generic.id,info.userId,info._children.gigId.userId,info.accepted,info.cancelled,info.paymentTerms)}}`

with the following function header:

`_showCancel: function(viewerUserId,offerUserId,gigUserId, accepted, cancel, paymentTerms)`.

But then inside the function, you reference `info.accepted` and `info.cancelled`, whereas you should used `accepted` and `cancelled`.

This is because inside the function, the referenced values will always be up-to-date, whereas referencing variables via `this.<variable-name>` can sometimes contain older values.

In order for my answer to be complete, I will also explain certain "problems" with other ways.

**Way 2**: Here, you only reference the Object as a whole. This won't trigger the call via subproperty change, so it won't work as desired.

**Way 3** and **Way 4** are similar, and both are overkills. With the `object.*` notation, you listen to **all** subproperty changes, which you most likely *don't want*.

### tl;dr

Go with "**Way 1**" and make things simpler by using computed properties.

To do this, change:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_showCancel(userData.generic.id,info.userId,info._children.gigId.userId,info.accepted,info.cancelled,info.paymentTerms)}}">
```

To:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isCanceled}}">
```

And add the following computed property to the Polymer element:

```
isCanceled: {
  type: Boolean,
  computed: '_showCancel(userData.generic.id,info.userId,info._children.gigId.userId,info.accepted,info.cancelled,info.paymentTerms)'
}
```

You already have `_showCancel` defined, so this is actually it. The code should work the same as your "**Way 1**" example, only the `dom-if` is cleaner. This is especially useful if you re-use the condition on multiple occurences.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate do add a comment about it.

Comment: Having the full info.cancelled is a typo leftover from cut and pasting code. Thank you for your answer, especially for the computed property  idea!!!

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer. I accepted it... and I also added an addendum question. I know there is no incentive to you to answer, but it would be awesome if you could :D